# Simultaneonus NX client connections

Tags: linux, freenx

I would like to have two separate NX connections for the same username going from one dual-monitor client to NX server. The idea is to get two separate same username KDE sessions. When I try to do it the most obvious way (by starting one NX client on each separate monitor), second connection just over takes the first one. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias username in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` (using the same `$HOME` and `$SHELL` and password).

But be aware that 2 parallel KDE sessions may still be creating conflicting settings in `$HOME/.kde*` files -- so this may not work well (but that wouldn't be an NX/FreeNX problem per se...).